# Updates in mysql transaction - isolation

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency, transactions

I have following model

```
Inventory [product_name, quantity, reserved_quantity]
```

with data

```
[Shirt, 1, 0] 
[Shorts, 10, 0]
```

What happens if following code is executed in multiple threads at the same time?

```
 $changes = [
             ['name' => 'Shirt', 'qty' => 1],
             ['name' => 'Shorts', 'qty' => 1],
            ];
 $db->startTransaction();
 foreach($changes as $change){
     $rowsUpdated = $db->exec("UPDATE inventory 
            SET reserved_quantity = reserved_quantity + $change['qty']
            WHERE product_name = $change['name']
                 and quantity >= reserved_quantity + $change['qty']");
     if($rowsUpdated !== 1)
       $db->rollback();
       exit;
}
$db->commit();
```

Is it possible that the result will be?

```
[Shirt, 1, 2]
[Shorts, 10, 2]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not.
Lets see what would be happening in the following scenario:

1. The *first* transaction starts
2. `UPDATE` **Shirt** => an exclusive row lock will be set on the  record
3. The *second* transaction starts
4. The *second* transaction tries to `UPDATE` **Shirt**. As it would need to obtain a record lock it would wait as this record has already been locked by the *first* transaction
5. The *first* transaction commits, the *second* one would resume execution and see the updated record

Of course it's only relevant to InnoDb and similar mysql engines.
Please note that you're lucky enough that traversing the records in the same order. If it were not the case you might run into a [deadlock](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-deadlocks.html)

Comment: Thanks ffeast! So the row lock is there until transaction is not committed or rollbacked even if I don't require it explicitly with select for update?

Comment: Thanks a lot! You're right. I just made some prototyping and works as you descripbed.